# Can someone explain this php string behavior

Tags: php, html, string, parsing

Reading a line of text with the character < in it chops the string at that position, but changing the '<' to a '[', restores the entire string;

```php
$buffer = '(18:07:18.206)(01426)DISPATCH: RX DSCHUTEANSW: status=0x20c001 gp [10 0 0 0 0] l_code_sc=16 code_sc=<SDtGt15JRK_001>';

echo $buffer . '<br>';

$buffer = str_replace('<', '[', $buffer);

echo $buffer . '<br>';
```

```
(18:07:18.206)(01426)DISPATCH: RX DSCHUTEANSW: status=0x20c001 gp [10 0 0 0 0] l_code_sc=16 code_sc=

(18:07:18.206)(01426)DISPATCH: RX DSCHUTEANSW: status=0x20c001 gp [10 0 0 0 0] l_code_sc=16 code_sc=[SDtGt15JRK_001>
```

Comment: Can't replicate... https://3v4l.org/u1JAJ

Comment: WAMPServer 3.1.7 64

Apache 2.4.37

PHP 7.2.14

Comment: I get it now. I assume you try to output this in a html and not in a console? The `< >` will make the browser read it as a html tag and make it invisible to the user. If you look at the source it's sill there.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the source code in your browser, it's all still there.

< is treated as an opening HTML tag by your browser, so the string isn't displayed after the <.

Use this instead:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($buffer) . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with PHP parsing the string but how the web browser interprets that string. The browser considers any string within `< >` as an HTML tag and does not display the tag directly on the screen.

In order to escape the symbol and display it on screen, you can use the `htmlentities` function in PHP. ([Ref](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php))

You can use it as follows:

```
$buffer = '(18:07:18.206)(01426)DISPATCH: RX DSCHUTEANSW: status=0x20c001 gp [10 0 0 0 0] l_code_sc=16 code_sc=<SDtGt15JRK_001>';

echo htmlentities($buffer) . '<br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because browser interprets the text `<SDtGt15JRK_001>` as html tag and do not show it, even if you convert it to string then also behaviour is same.

If you wish to show this text as well in browser then you need to use `htmlspecialchars` to show tag as below:-

```
$buffer = "(18:07:18.206)(01426)DISPATCH: RX DSCHUTEANSW: status=0x20c001 gp [10 0 0 0 0] l_code_sc=16 code_sc=<SDtGt15JRK_001>";

echo htmlspecialchars($buffer) . '<br>'; //use htmlspecialchars
```

**Output:-**

```
(18:07:18.206)(01426)DISPATCH: RX DSCHUTEANSW: status=0x20c001 gp [10 0 0 0 0] l_code_sc=16 code_sc=<SDtGt15JRK_001>
```